# Laravel - SELF:: usage in models

Tags: php, laravel

so I got this model that has only **$fillable** defined, no **$table** in it.

The model has this function:

```
public static function gamesToday()
{
    return self::where('status', self::STATUS_FINISHED)->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->count();
}
```

The model works correctly and returns the correct value, but how does it know from which table to return the value?

Is there a way to define the **$table** somewhere else?

Or am I misunderstanding how `self::` works?

**EDIT:**

In views it's used like this:

```
<div class="totalGamesPlayed">{{ \App\Game::gamesToday() }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your class name. Example: model `User`, class `User` inside `User.php` If there is no `table` property inside the model, table set as class name in lower case in the plural - table `users`
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Answer (score 0):

It will return the matching records from the current model in which you have put this method. You can specify table name for the model using it's protected $table property.

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name_here';
```

Comment: The funny thing is that it works without the `$table` being defined in that model, my question is how?

Comment: It takes from the naming convention. for example: your model class is User then it will automatically take 'users' as a table name if you don't define. please check the following link: http://www.rappasoft.com/articles/laravel-eloquent-naming-convention-guide/